# Javafx TreeTableView enable Show/Hide columns button

Tags: javafx, treetableview

https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/TreeTableView+User+Experience+Documentation

Can someone help me enable Show/Hide button for columns in TreeTableView?
In the above documentation it is showing the screenshot for the same but I am not able to enable it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
treeTableView.setTableMenuButtonVisible(true);
```